# How to ignore a click on a Gutenberg block that is wrapped with a link tag?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have created a custom Gutenberg block that is basically a link. When I click the block in the editor I immediately get sent to the page the block links to instead of being able to edit the block. How do I stop this from happening? I've already tried putting `pointer-events: none` as a style on it but that doesn't do anything surprisingly.

```
<a href="<?php the_field('link') ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr($id); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr($className); ?> <?php echo esc_attr($layout); ?>">

<div class="icon_callout_content">
    <div class="off_content">
        <div class="color_callout_icon">
            <img src="<?php echo $icon ?>" height="<?php if($iconHeight){ echo $iconHeight . "px"; } ?>">
        </div>
        <h3><?php echo $title ?></h3>
    </div>

    <div class="hover_content">
        <?php echo $description ?>
    </div>
</div>

</a>
```

Comment: Wrap the `<a href=.....` in a `if ( ! is_admin() ) {}` That will make sure that the link won't output in the admin area.

Answer (score 0):

Since this may help others in the future, wrap your `<a>` tag in an `if` statement to check if your in the admin area. If you are, then it won't output those tags.

```
<?php if ( ! is_admin() ) : ?>
<a href="<?php the_field('link') ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr($id); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr($className); ?> <?php echo esc_attr($layout); ?>">
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="icon_callout_content">
    <div class="off_content">
        <div class="color_callout_icon">
            <img src="<?php echo $icon ?>" height="<?php if($iconHeight){ echo $iconHeight . "px"; } ?>">
        </div>
        <h3><?php echo $title ?></h3>
    </div>

    <div class="hover_content">
        <?php echo $description ?>
    </div>
</div>


<?php if ( ! is_admin() ) : ?>
</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```